# How to use process class in c#?

Tags: c#

I use this code to run some cmd commands:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C vpncli.exe -s < data.dat & vpncli.exe status " +
            "> C:\\BicoinMiningProject\\BitcoinCloudMiningBypassApp\\BitcoinMiningProject" +
            "\\BitcoinCloudMiningBypassApp\\bin\\Debug\\VPN_Status.txt");
```

this works fine. but I need to use it like this:

```
using (var pro = new Process())
        {
            pro.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32";
            pro.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            pro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pro.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C vpncli.exe -s < data.dat & vpncli.exe status " +
                "> C:\\BicoinMiningProject\\BitcoinCloudMiningBypassApp\\BitcoinMiningProject" +
                "\\BitcoinCloudMiningBypassApp\\bin\\Debug\\VPN_Status.txt";
            pro.Start();
            pro.StandardInput.Flush();
            pro.StandardInput.Close();
            pro.WaitForExit();

        }
```

because I need to wait for finishing the process before continue.

this is not working. the cmd is opened but immediately close before running any command.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Remove call to `Flush` and `Close`, leave `WaitForExit` right after `Start()`

Comment: Change `/C` by `/K` the command window will not close, and you will be able to see error messages if any.

Comment: @RobertBaron still not working. it also keep cmd open but show nothing in it. just a black screen.

Comment: Can't you simply do `Process.Start("...").WaitForExit();` ?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thank you!! it works!   but why the hell the other code that I wrote, does not work?!  I check it out so many times, try lot of different way, but nothing.